# Error Store Load

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, store, sencha-touch-2

Good evening.

The initial view of my application need to get some data from a Store (autoLoad = true) to change some components of it. At what point can I do this?

View:

```
    Ext.define('App.view.EmpresaPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.empresapanel',

    config: {
        ui: 'dark',
        layout: {
            type: 'card'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Menu',
                layout: {
                    align: 'center',
                    type: 'hbox'
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'bottom',
                title: '2012 ©',
                layout: {
                    align: 'center',
                    type: 'hbox'
                }
            }       
        ]
    }

});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Empresa', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'App.model.Empresa'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'App.model.Empresa',
        storeId: 'EmpresaStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://URL',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'empresa'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Empresa', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            empresaPanel: 'empresapanel'
        },

        control: {
            "empresapanel": {
                initialize: 'onContainerInitialize'
            }
        }
    },

    onContainerInitialize: function(component, options) {
        var store = Ext.getStore("EmpresaStore"),
        record = store.findRecord("id", "1");

        console.log(store);
        console.log(record);

    }

});
```

First appears in console.log: `Ext.apply.create.Class`
In the second: `null`

If I put a button in this view and tap the same event I run the same code that is in the function "onContainerInitialize" the record is completed.

Is there a specific time after the creation of view where you can access data from the Store?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are asking how you detect when the store data has been loaded, just listen to the 'load' event in your store...

Answer (score 1):

You should add listener for [store load event](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load) to access record from the store.
Here is an example how you can do it. Put following code inside of the onContainerInitialize:

```
store.on('load', function(t) {
    var record = t.findRecord("id", "1");
    console.log(record);
}, this, {single: true});
```